# Docker Default Operating System

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am looking at a docker file which does not specify a specific base image operating system (like FROM ubuntu: 14:04). Is there any specification on the default operating system used when building an image (and not specifying a base os-image)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You always should have a FROM instruction for a Dockerfile as per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) as mentioned by Munir. However, you can choose variety of base images, which does not have to be an OS for your Dockerfile. For example, if you are creating a docker image for your java application, you can use java image as your base images.

```
FROM library/java
```

However, at the end, if you traverse thorough those image's Dockerfile, you will end up in one or the other OS. Java is based on Debian.

Comment: exactly what I figured out it the end. but thanks a lot for the confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

according to the docker reference https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

> Docker runs the instructions in a **Dockerfile** in order. **The first
>   instruction must be `FROM`** in order to specify the Base Image from
>   which you are building.

Comment: my bad: I did not realize that FROM java:8 actually pulls debian.